# Accessing an ftl file under WEB-INF in a Java Project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I am using `Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)` for my `Java Spring MVC Web Application`. I am trying to access an ftl file placed in a subfolder under `WEB-INF` and read its value to a string. I am using the following code:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/abc/sub1/sub2/message.ftl");
InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
String message = IOUtils.toString(resourceInputStream, "UTF-8");
```

But I am getting a file not found exception. The exact path of the file is `/my-project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/abc/sub1/sub2/message.ftl`

How can I read the contents of that file to a string.

Comment: Try to use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("message.ftl")`

Comment: you should try servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/...path to your file");

Comment: @ Michael Meyer, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

the path should be `/WEB-INF/jsp/modules/abc/sub1/sub2/message.ftl`. `src/main/whatever` is  a maven convention, your container doesn't know anything about it.

The war file deployed in the container will not have any `src/main/*`